# Parameter Integral Sin function, Gamma function

Tags: definite-integrals

Given $$ F: A \in\Bbb{R}\rightarrow\Bbb{R}$$ such that $$F(y)=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2} (sinx)^y(cosx)^{1-y} \; dx$$

Prove that $F(1/2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt\pi}(\Gamma(3/4))^2$ and then find the maximum domain $A$ such that $F$ exists.
$$\Gamma(s)= \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{s-1}dt$$

I arrived at $F(1/2)=\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt\sin2x\;dx$ and that is about all that I can do.

Comment: Have a look at the formulas for the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). Also, it is not clear to me what you mean by finding $A$.

Comment: Wikipedia? Seriously?

Comment: Find the maximum domain A for such a function F

Comment: why not? If the relevant formula is there, why should we not link to it? I also think you should update your question regarding $A$.

Comment: I need a proof that's why

Comment: Sure, I can write a proof... But remember, don't be rude next time you ask for help :)

Comment: Sorry if I seemed rude. I knew of that formula and let's just say preparation for my exams has not been going very well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define
$$
\Gamma(z)=\int_0^{+\infty} t^{z-1}e^{-t}\,dt
$$
and
$$
B(z,w)=\int_0^1 t^{w-1}(1-t)^{z-1}\,dt.
$$

Then you should be able to conclude what you want from the following two results.

> It holds that
>   $$
> B(z,w)=\frac{\Gamma(z)\Gamma(w)}{\Gamma(z+w)}.
> $$

*Proof*

We make a calculation, changing coordinates,
$$
\begin{align}
\Gamma(z+w)B(z,w)&=\Gamma(z+w)\int_0^1 t^{w-1}(1-t)^{z-1}\,dt\\
&=[t=u/(1+u)]\\
&=\Gamma(z+w)\int_0^{+\infty} u^{w-1}\Bigl(\frac{1}{1+u}\Bigr)^{z+w}\,du\\
&=\int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty} u^{w-1}\Bigl(\frac{1}{1+u}\Bigr)^{z+w} e^{-v}\,dv\,du\\
&=[s=v/(1+u)]\\
&=\int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}u^{w-1}s^{z+w-1}e^{-s(u+1)}\,ds\,du\\
&=\int_0^{+\infty}s^ze^{-s}\int_0^{+\infty}(us)^{w-1}e^{-su}\,du\,ds\\
&=\int_0^{+\infty}s^{z-1}e^{-s}\Gamma(w)\,ds\\
&=\Gamma(z)\Gamma(w).
\end{align}
$$

> The following is valid for $a>-1$ and $b>-1$
>   $$
> \int_0^{\pi/2}(\sin \phi)^a(\cos\phi)^b\,d\phi = \frac{1}{2}B\bigl(\tfrac{a+1}{2},\tfrac{b+1}{2}\bigr).
> $$

*Proof*

Just let $u=(\sin\phi)^2$.

Comment: Any ideas on how to find A? I have the vague feeling A is the interval [0,1]

Comment: Hint: Look at the conditions on $a$ and $b$ in the last integral.

Comment: Yes. So y>-1 and 1-y>-1. A is the open interval (-1,2).That should do it